# Integrate app dynamics in the Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, appdynamics

I am new to the AppDynamics. We want to integrate AppDynamics in our Angular application (It is intranet Single Page Application).

I saw this page but this is about AngularJS not Angular.

https://www.appdynamics.com/supported-technologies/java/angularjs-monitoring

We are using Cloud Foundry to host our application. There is no issues at backend service. Since it comes with property files where we added AppDynamic entries and then when we push our application it will be integrated with AppDynamics.

But where as Angular doesn't have that configuration.

So any suggestion about how to integrate AppDynamics to an Angular Application.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are wanting is info around instrumentation of the front end of an Angular SPA.

Please see documentation here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Monitor+Single-Page+Applications - Angular is mentioned as being available using SPA2.

(Note for the front end we use Javascript BRUM for monitoring, general docs are here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/Browser+Monitoring - this is a seperate part of the product than the APM used to monitor backends)